# Python data.table from h2o

Tags: python, h2o

I've seen two H2O demos including Sri's keynote at H2O World 2017, and they have mentioned a Python version of the R data.table package.  However, I have been unable to find any additional info regarding this.

Is this available as a stand alone python module (or planning on becoming one)?

Comment: I guess they talked about `pandas`

Comment: See http://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/pandas_datatable.html

Comment: I don't think they were referring to pandas, Sri specifically said they spent a lot of development time building a python version of data.table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. H2O is currently developing Python `datatable` package, with the goal to make it as close to R's `data.table` as possible, both in syntax and in speed. The package will be released open source once it has a certain minimal number of features. Currently there is no set date for the release, but we hope to do it before the end of March.

---

**UPDATE**: [datatable](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) is now publicly open.

Comment: Excellent looking forward to it

Comment: Need some *examples* /documentation to make this useful: